# GCP syslog server not receiving logs from onsite firewall

Tags: google-cloud-platform, routes, vpn, syslog

I had a need for a simple syslog server where I can store the logs for my onsite firewall.  To do this, I created a GCP instance and have installed Graylog on it.  From GCP and from my onsite workstation I can access the Graylog servers dashboard and I have configured the syslog input to receive the syslogs on port 514 as they are sent from my local firewalls internal ip address, but the Graylog input moves into failed status and shows no data received.

I have a previous VPN in place that connects my onsite to GCP and it has worked as expected for well over a year, this VPN is to be used to send the syslog data from local firewall over to the new GCP syslog instance.  I have added the necessary firewall tags in GCP to grant the necessary access for my local firewall and the GCP syslog instance to be able to communicate with each other as well as double checked that the local and remote ip's configured are all allowed over the VPN.
ve also double checked my GCP and local firewall rules and they appear to be correctly in place.

As a test, I can locally ssh into the local firewall and then use a shell to attempt to connect to the GCP instance via ssh (or even telnet or tracert) I receive a "**No route to host**" message, but when testing from my local workstation to the GCP instance the necessary access DOES seems to be there.

Additionally, from my workstation even a simple ping test is successful, but it is not successful when I try the same test while ssh'd into the Firewall.  Could the problem be that the local firewall (which is the one I want to send logs from) is using internal IP of (lets say) 10.1.0.1 and GCP doesn't accept or route that traffic?  \

Is there something in GCP that would restrict traffic from the Firewall x.x.x.1 IP address and it isn't allowing it to send logs out to my syslog server in GCP?

Or am I overcomplicating this and missing an easier solution for retaining our onsite firewall logs in the cloud.. Is there a way to use buckets for long time storage of my firewall logs.

I would greatly appreciate any input that can put me on the right track!  I've looked at this long enough that I seem to be going in circles.  Thanks in advance!

It was my hope that the new syslog server would accept the connection from my local firewall.  The no routes available message is really throwing me, since this connection should be doing the same thing as when I test from my local workstation.

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde - your document requires using google.com credentials.

Comment: Attaching [troubleshooting document](https://www.alphr.com/no-route-to-host-error-in-linux-what-to-do/#:~:text=%27No%20Route%20to%20Host%27%20denotes,because%20of%20an%20inappropriate%20setup) by william stanton which will help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks @SaiChandraGadde I think my issue lies in the fact that my firewall (that's supposed to be sending the logs) can't route itself over the vpn.  The firewall I'm using is based on a Ubuntu kernel, and while it has rules in place for accepting or denying traffic from one network to another and routing over VPN, there does not seem to be anything in place for routing traffic that originates with itself.   
 If the logs needed were originated some place else there would be no issue.  I will reach out to the vender, but sadly have not had much luck with them in the past on other issues.